# Remove all rows from dataframe where multiple conditions are not met using R and Lubridate

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I am trying to take a data frame of dates that is named test:

```
structure(list(`1` = structure(c(1301641140, 1306861140, 1306947540, 
1310403540, 1312394340, 1314982740, 1320044340, 1321599540, 1323413940, 
1325660340, 1329116340, 1331017140, 1335808740, 1338220740, 1341075540, 
1341161940, 1343926740, 1346518740, 1351537140, 1354172340, 1356249540, 
1358837940, 1359961140, 1362376740, 1364972340, 1369846740, 1371056340, 
1374080340, 1377968340, 1378832340, 1382774340, 1385625540, 1386917940, 
1389077940, 1393484340, 1393873140, 1397631540, 1401292740, 1403024340, 
1404320340, 1408726740, 1409677140, 1412269140, 1416376740, 1418367540, 
1420700340, 1424415540, 1425625140, 1428220740, 1431359940, 1434560340, 
1438189140, 1438707540, 1441213140, 1444237140, 1448261940, 1450598340, 
1453186740, 1455087540, 1456984740, 1461776340, 1464713940, 1465919940, 
1469465940, 1471366740, 1473440340, 1476896340, 1479711540, 1481353140, 
1483862340, 1486709940, 1489647540), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `2` = structure(c(1302533940, 1306850340, 
1308153540, 1311782340, 1312383540, 1314892740, 1318867140, 1322643540, 
1322726340, 1325667540, 1329724740, 1332950340, 1335794340, 1338307140, 
1340639940, 1343228340, 1343833140, 1346767140, 1349366340, 1354175940, 
1355385540, 1358845140, 1362049140, 1363251540, 1366293540, 1369843140, 
1371052740, 1374073140, 1375977540, 1378828740, 1380725940, 1384415940, 
1386925140, 1390985940, 1391680740, 1393847940, 1398686340, 1400770740, 
1403103540, 1405349940, 1407340740, 1410364740, 1412175540, 1416301140, 
1418288340, 1420707540, 1424336340, 1425628740, 1428591540, 1432141140, 
1435157940, 1436975940, 1438790340, 1441292340, 1444226340, 1448269140, 
1449215940, 1453201140, 1455091140, 1458550740, 1461859140, 1464278340, 
1466697540, 1469545140, 1472133540, 1473951540, 1475596740, 1478015940, 
1482137940, 1483945140, 1486713540, 1490803140), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("1", "2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and remove the ROWS from every column where the month number is not 1, 2, 3, 11, or 12. (January February, March, November, December). I can get the month number by using lubridate like so:

```
apply(test, 2, month)
```

How can I remove rows from every column where the above apply returns an unwanted number?

**EDIT**

The dput above is actually of a test data frame. My actually data frame has 71 columns.

Comment: If your data can be converted from wide format to long format, it will be much easier for all similar tasks. Check the topic of tidy data, reshape, wide vs long format etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility,

```
library(lubridate)

test[rowSums(sapply(test, function(i) month(i) %in% c(1,2,3,11,12))) == ncol(test),]
```

If you have rows that 1 column satisfies the condition and another doesn't, then you can replace unwanted dates with NA, i.e.

```
test[sapply(test, function(i) !month(i) %in% c(1,2,3,11,12))] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which column is to be tested since column `1` and `2` both have datetimes.

This is for column `1`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[month(`1`) %in% c(1, 2, 3, 11, 12)]
```

Comment: Every column needs to be tested. I have edited my question to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion.